# How can I prevent calling a super function from the derived class function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two classes

```
class A {
  unset() {
    new B().unset();
  }
}

class B  extends A {
 flag : boolean;
 unset() {
  this.flag = false;
  // super.unset() I don't want someone accidentally call this line here
 }
}
```

So in this code, I want to prevent another developer not to call super.unset() inside class B unset function; it will become cyclic otherwise. How can I prevent calling a super function from the derived class function?

Comment: The example doesn't call super?

Comment: Normally the solution to "How do I prevent another dev doing X", is to leave a comment explaining why it's a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent"? Are they going to be editing this code? Are they writing code which uses B/A?

Comment: @evolutionxbox other developers are going to use class A to create other classes like B. So I want to ask if we can set something that shows waring that we can not call superclass unset function from derived classes.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8gew) work for you?  The idea is to widen the observed type of `A` so that it no longer contains an `unset()` method.  The subclass is then seen as creating a new `unset()` instead of overriding it.  I don't think there's any way to have this be conditional on whether or not `B` actually implements `unset()`, so it might not be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the decision  of creating new child instance from parent method. But here is what I think might help you in preventing the `super` access:

```
class A {
  unset() {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === A.prototype) {
      console.log("Allowed")
      new B().unset();
    } else {
      console.log("Not Allowed")
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
 unset() {
  this.flag = false;
  super.unset() //I don't want someone accidentally call this line here
 }
}

new B().unset()
new A().unset()
```

Let me know if this doesnt work for you.

Comment: Please be aware that using `__proto__` may break in future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox updated the answer. Let me know if it needs improvement